# Set shell icon in C++ without resource file

Tags: c++, windows, icons, mingw-w64, msys2

If there's already a PNG image in the code, that's used as the window icon (among other places), is it possible to also set it as the executable icon when compiled on Windows, without an .rc/res file?

Comment: The icon that's displayed for an executable image must be compiled into the executable image as a resource.

Comment: But why not use a resource file?

Comment: @IInspectable But you can make [internal resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcew), right?

Comment: @EnoshCohen Various reasons, mainly related to the fact that the software is mainly for Linux, so I'm curious to find out whether there's a way to add an icon to the Windows executable, without introducing 3 additional files.

Comment: That's a preprocessor function-like macro. All it does is take a resource ID as an integer and return the same value typed as a string, which is what many resource management functions expect. Although it appears that you have misidentified the problem you are trying to solve. If you want your application to compile for Linux and Windows, adjust your build system to acknowledge differences in resource management. You are already invoking different linkers, so all you need to do is adjust your link step for Windows and link the icon resources into the executable.

Comment: @IInspectable The build system already accounts for both, yet neither have a shell icon, but both have a window icon (icon in the top left of the window border). Also, there is no icon resource, since it's not needed for Linux. A side effect of that is, when building for windows (which works just fine, there is no compatibility/build issue with windows), you are left with an iconless executable.

Comment: I don't understand the rationale. If you have a dedicated Windows linker step, just compile your icon resource into a binary format (using rc.exe) that can be linked into the final executable. You don't even need to change or write a single line of code.

Comment: @IInspectable I am very well aware of that method. The aforementioned PNG image is not a file, it exists within the source code as a byte array. Now, sure, I can dump it into an .ico file => .rc => .res =>  .exe (it _is_ my backup plan). I'm just curious, if there's a way to compile the image as it is (a byte array) to a res, just to trim down a few of those steps and avoid keeping a duplicate of an image, that already exists in the source tree. All the documentation I've read only mention providing a path to an ico file as the only input.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But if you just want to prevent that the PNG is duplicated in the final executable, you could use the resource (`LoadResource`) instead of the byte array in the windows build.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) on the created executable to edit the executable resources (among other things, change the icon).

Comment: I am very well aware of Resource Hacker and alternative, but I'm looking for a build-time solution.